# Mysql multiplication query

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table called products containing a field called price and I simply want to double the price on every product. Could you give me a hand with an SQL statement I can run within PHP myAdmin please.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
update products set price = price * 2;
```

Answer (score 8):

it's as easy as

```
UPDATE
  products
SET
  price = price*2;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE products SET price = price + price;
```

Didn't want to use multiplication :P

Comment: @ErdalG. That is a good question. (But usually it doesn't matter)

Comment: @Annabel Usually not, indeed. It's pure curiosity :)