# How to multiply a value

Tags: mysql

I've a table called WP_POSTMETA with a column META_KEY and a column META_VALUE.

I'd like to multiply the META_VALUE '_PRICE' with a factor 1.5

Who can help me with the right MYSQL query? I have to multiply prices for about 8000+ items and want to update them all in one action...

Please see also

[image]

Comment: The question already exists : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015429/mysql-multiplication-query

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:-

```
Update WP_POSTMETA
SET META_VALUE = Meta_Value*1.5
WHERE META_KEY = '_PRICE'
```

Comment: Thank you! Works without 'table'.

Comment: @EWM:- Yes that was a necessary change. Thanks for pointing that! Done that mistake in a hurry! Updated the correct one! :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand correctly...

You want to update the Meta_value * 1.5 where the meta_key = '_PRICE'

```
Update WP_POSTMETA
SET META_VALUE = Meta_Value*1.5
WHERE META_KEY = '_PRICE'
```

To view the results before you run the above update. update..

```
Select MEta_value*1.5 as newVal, Meta_value, Meta_key
from  WP_POSTMETA
WHERE META_KEY = '_PRICE'
```

Comment: I don't think you meant to have the - sign before Meta_Value

Comment: Thank you! Works without 'table'.

Answer (score 0):

Or like this with a transaction:

```
BEGIN;

Update WP_POSTMETA
SET META_VALUE = Meta_Value*1.5
WHERE META_KEY = '_PRICE'



Select MEta_value*1.5 as newVal, Meta_value, Meta_key
from  WP_POSTMETA
WHERE META_KEY = '_PRICE'
```

If you're happy with the result

```
COMMIT;
```

Else do a rollback

```
ROLLBACK;
```

Actually you should do all statements that modifies production data in a transaction.